# MVC paths in Extjs

Tags: extjs, path, extjs-mvc

I have got a ExtJs application (MVC).

So, I define many controllers, models, views and stores.
At now, the structure of my project is not easy.

For example my model:

```
Ext.define('KP.model.account.AccountList', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['parameter', 'string_value']

});
```

I define my store with model like this:

```
Ext.define('KP.store.account.AccountList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.s_AccountList',

    model: 'KP.model.account.AccountList',
    ......................................
});
```

If I want to move some .js files, I must rewrite many paths in classes definitions.
So, how can I declare my classes (by alias maybe) and use them more effectively?
It's need, If I move files on files tree.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The MVC of ExtJS is heavily based on tree folder structure. Take as example a view defined like this: `KP.view.account.AccountList`. Well, ExtJS expects to find a file called AccountList.js in `your_dir_app/view/account/`.
Even if you find a solution (for example, using alias (but I don't think so)), I will suggest you to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe stores are the only classes that refer to Model classes by their full name. Controllers refer to model classes by their name minus the 'AppName.model' prefix. So a model `MyApp.model.User` is referred in the controller class as simply `User`.
If you have a finer grain separation of code than `MyApp.model.specific.User` is referred by controller as `specific.User` .

Aliases are used to register xtypes and are also used by the `Ext.widget` method.